# PL/SQL Procedure compiled with errors

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql, procedure

I am a newbie to PL/SQL. This is the block I executed :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DoctorandNurse (id number, name varchar2, dno number, timings varchar2, contact number, gender char, email varchar2, salary number, doj date, post varchar2) AS
salary_exception EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
IF salary >= 2500000 THEN raise salary_exception;
ELSE
insert into Doctor_Nurse values(id,name,dno,timings,contact,gender,email,salary,doj,post);
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN salary_exception THEN DMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Salary should be less than or equal to Rs. 25,00,000.');
END;
```

The compiler reported that the procedure was created with compilation error. What is the error exactly. Please ask for additional information if required.

Comment: Please issue the command, `show errors`, and provide the results.

Comment: This is the error as i said before : Procedure created with compilation error. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SQL*Plus, the following will work:

`SQL> sho err`

Not sure about the rest of clients, but most should support this syntax.

Comment: This fixed the problem once I saw the error. The error was a syntactical error. DBMS._OUTPUT.PUT_LINE. I missed the B.